# process an image to separate chars from a word

Tags: python, image, image-processing, imagefilter

what strategy use to filter/process an image in order to separate chars from a image?

for example:

[image]

I need this ir order to make an OCR read text in image with better efectivity.

Comment: try dilating the image and then finding edges..

Answer (score 1):

Pre-processing images for OCR is a complicated task, although well documented in textbooks and image processing material.

One library with Python bindings that has all the most-used algorithms used in these steps is Leptonica - check [Leptonica](http://www.leptonica.com/) and [pyleptonica](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyleptonica/0.8) to use it from Python.

As for the documentation of the steps, maybe some googling can get you better results than I could in this answer, shrot of rewrittng the textbook I have here (it is in Portuguese, so I think passing its reference would not help either)